# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: NL Exception was generated

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

Getting java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: NL Exception was generated

Trying to connect to Oracle sql developer DB.

Connection string used is :

```
 jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(CID=ValidCID)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ValidHost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID =ValidSID)(SERVER = DEDICATED))); User Id=UID;Password=Pwd;
```

I use the same set of parameters while connecting from QTP. What could be the issue here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it...

instead of supplying User ID and password through connection string, one needs to supply them through the method.
So, my connection string would become

```
 String strConnString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(CID=ValidCID)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ValidHost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID =ValidSID)(SERVER = DEDICATED)))";
```

and I would use the following method to creation a connection

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.GetConnection(strConnString, UserID, Password);
```